# What is the source of Class revtex4-1 Warning when compiling a tex file in overleaf?

Tags: document-classes, revtex, class-options, clearpage

When working on my paper on overleaf, I notice that the compilation runs with no error and produces the final version of the paper but there is an annoying warning which I don't seem to know its cause as it only points to empty lines between some of my paragraphs in the `.tex` file. Here is the complete warning message I am receiving.

> ./my_file.tex: Class revtex4-1 Warning: Deferred float stuck
>   during \clearpage processing.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
And here is a short version of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{aastex61}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vdag}{(v)^\dagger}
\newcommand\aastex{AAS\TeX}
\newcommand\latex{La\TeX}

\submitjournal{ApJ}

\shorttitle{short title}
\shortauthors{Smith et al.}



\begin{document}

\title{title}
\correspondingauthor{main author}
\email{some emails}

\author{main author}
\affiliation{main author’s school}

\author{second author}
\affiliation{second author school}

\author{third author}
\affil{third author’s school}

\begin{abstract}
some abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{k}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Methodology and Analyses}  \label{Section 2}
\subsection{first subsection} \label{Section 2.1}


%some sections and subsections go in here in the form of paragraphs separated by an empty line by pressing Enter key twice.


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\LaTeX` exists as command or `\LaTeXe` ...

Comment: the posted example does not appear to give the warning (so does not help answer the question)

Comment: I have long paper with many paragraphs. I just didn't want to post everything. But, now I am trying to include at least those parts surrounding the problematic lines.

Comment: A float is a `figure` or `table` environment (it's possible to define others, but those are the defaults).  Deferred means that it doesn't get typeset where you put it, but at some later point.  So the thing you want to look for is a table or figure that is much later than you think it should be.

Comment: don't post a fragment, make a small complete document (using dummy text) that makes the warning, otherwise it is very hard for anyone to debug

Comment: the standard latex output routine always ensures after a `\clearpage` that all floats are output, the modified vesion in revtex does not ensure that, but gives this warning when it detects that it has failed, without an example, hard to say why

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the warning with a MWE. I guess I have the same problem as this post and it seems that it is still an open question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155564/a-float-is-stuck-cannot-be-placed